# Can I use another software instead of android studio to run react native app

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, facebook-android-sdk, expo

I am trying to run hello world in react native without Android Studio. My mobile phone is only 4.2.1 which is not supporting Expo to install in my phone as it requires 6.0. I want run react native app in my phone (4.2.1) without Expo and Android Studio. How is it possible?

Comment: do you have android sdk in your pc ?

Comment: Yes , I just installed it

Comment: For run your app on your mobile phone you can change
minSdkVersion (as per your phone OS version) in your build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Just run `react-native run-android` at the root folder of your project in the Terminal. Keep your Android Emulator open. To open your emulator, use the `emulator` command from your Android sdk folder.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps :
1) Run the emulator from Android studio. Connect your device to system. Select it when the IDE asks to select the device.
2) Now run react-native run-android from the root of the directory.

This should solve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your terminal to run the react-native app.

1. Get android SDK.
2. Set path for your android sdk in bash.
3. For using virtual device you can simply run 'android avd' command in your terminal and create a new avd device. Or use your own phone by simply plugging it in.
4. Go to the root folder of your project. Now run 'react-native run-android'.
5. A JS server will start and then the app dependencies will be resolved and a debug-apk will get installed on your avd/device.

Answer (score 0):

You can download older version for expo to run your native app.